# Break line in node.js

Tags: node.js, lambda, line-breaks

i want to break a line and used \n but its not working. creating Lambda  function.

```
callback(buildFulfilmentResult('Fulfilled',"Thanks, for using our services " +item.Name+  " Your Flight status is Confirmed \n Arrival city: " +item.Arrival_city));
```

how to do then?

Comment: Depends on how you are checking if it's working or not. It should work, though it might not show a new line in log.

Comment: i am working on lext chatbot and checking my output on lex console

Comment: try using `\r\n` ?

Comment: @tcadidot0 didn't work

Answer (score 1):

we need more information about how the text is being displayed to give you a really good answer.

Handling line breaks is the responsibility of the entity handling the *display*, and so, what you need to send depends greatly on how the text is being displayed.

For example, if your chat bot is for the web, you might be able to get it to display line breaks by sending <br> instead of \n, since that is the line break code for HTML.

That said -- accepting and displaying raw HTML from your back end could represent a serious security risk.

If I was designing a this whole thing, I would use \n to represent the line break in NodeJS, and on the web where I displayed the text, I would

- take apart the string (string.split("\n")),
- create a new DOM element for each part of the string,
- make sure these elements were `display: block`, and
- put the text into each of those elements via the `.textContent` property.

This final step avoids making the browser parse HTML, mitigating that security risk.

Comment: callback(buildFulfilmentResult('Fulfilled',"Thanks, for using our services. " +item.Name+  " Your Flight status is Confirmed))                                                                                                i am displaying like this and see the output in lex chatbot console on Aws platfrom.